# TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webservice, react-native, fetch

Hola soy medio nuevo en React y estaba intentando hacer una aplicacion la cual se conecte con mi api pero me sale este error "TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function" y la linea que me dice que esta mal es la que guarda los datos en el state

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Posts extends Component {

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/posts')
        const data = await res.json();
        this.setState({posts: data})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Posts</h1>
                {
                    this.state.posts.map(post => {
                        return <div key={post._id}>
                            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                        </div>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

El error que me sale esta en la linea donde dice this,setState({posts: data})

Comment: Creo que (A) El error está en el método render, donde llamas a `this.state.posts.map`, y (B) La respuesta del fetch no es un array, sino un objeto, por lo que no tienes el método map presente

Comment: Yo creo que es la B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que declarar el `state`  en el `this`.

Cambia:

```
state = {
  posts: []
}
```

Por:

```
constructor()
{ 
  this.state = {
    posts: []
  };
}
```

Codigo completo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Posts extends Component {

    constructor()
    { 
      this.state = {
        posts: []
      };
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/posts')
        const data = await res.json();
        this.setState({posts: data})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Posts</h1>
                {
                    this.state.posts.map(post => {
                        return <div key={post._id}>
                            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                        </div>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Intente el modo que pusiste pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Intenta agregar `super();` antes del `this.state = { posts:[] }` y me dices.

Comment: El estado puede ser declarado fuera del constructor asi que ese no es el problema.